# What is the difference between Object and Objects in java

Tags: java

What's the difference between them and how can I use Objects?

```
Objects                 |        Object
java.util               |        java.lang
Class Objects           |        Class Object

java.util.Objects       |        java.lang.Object
```

Comment: `Objects` is a utility class for `Object`.

Comment: No need to use 'Objects', if it is necessary, the class 'Object' will use them

Comment: ... and you can look at its JavaDoc to see what these utility methods are:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html

Comment: @Phil Objects is quite useful...

Comment: @assylias I see, I did some reading up. Had previously thought you could access these methods through 'Object' aswell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc can help:

**java.lang.Object**

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy.
>   Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects,
>   including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

**java.util.Objects**

> This class consists of static utility methods for operating
>   on objects.  These utilities include  null-safe or 
>   null-tolerant methods for computing the hash code of an object,
>   returning a string for an object, and comparing two objects.

Comment: I wonder what the difference between null-safe and null-tolerant is.

Comment: @PieterDeBie It means if reference is not pointing to anyone or it is null, it will run and it will not show null pointer exception

Comment: So, no difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

`Object` is a implicit base class for all classes in java. `Objects` is a utility class introduced in java 7 that contains several very convenient static utility methods.

Comment: Objects indeed utility. However there is a lot to learn more.